# How to remove tab bar controller from super view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have added a tab bar controller which has 5 items as programatically, and then I want to back from each items to superview. How can I do this? removefromSuperView?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) hidetabbar:(BOOL)hiddenTabBar 
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    for(UIView *view in self.uiTabBarController.view.subviews){
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
            if (hiddenTabBar) {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            } else {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            }
        } else {
            if (hiddenTabBar) {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 431)];
            } else {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
            }
        }
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];  
}
```

[It would be preferable to visit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5816713/790794) to have better idea.